# Two adjectives for one noun, but only one is declined

Tags: adjective, declension

Two adjectives are used here, but only one of them is declined. Why?

> Die Ars Electronica ist das *weltweit wichtigste* Festival.

Regards

Comment: @wonderbear not only was it pretty much the same qeustion, but it was asked by the same person.

Comment: Note that "Die Ars Electronica ist ein weltweites, wichtiges Festival" would imply that it does not take place in a single city only, but rather all over the world. And "Die Ars Electronica ist das wichtigste weltweite Festival" would imply that it is the most important one among all such global festivals

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons for this:

### 1

The kind of [declension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declension) that is assigned to the adjective *»wichtig«* is a [comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_(grammar)) (in German: *Steigerung* or [Komparation](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komparation)). But not all adjectives can be compared. The three degrees of comparison are

- Positive: big, groß
- Comparative: bigger, größer
- Superlative: biggest, am größten

This is possible:

> wichtig - wichtiger - am wichtigsten
> important - more important - most important

But *weltweit* means *worldwide.* This is an adjective like *triangular* (*dreieckig*) or *only* (*einzig*). It makes no sense to say that something is "more only" or "more triangular" than something else, and also "more worldwide" makes just no sense.

---

### 2

The adjective *»weltweit«* (worldwide) is not an attribute of the noun *»Festival«.* A worldwide festival is possible only in fictional novels, because it means that the festival does not take place in a single place, but in every place on the surface of the planet Earth. But *Ars Electronica* is an existing festival. It takes place only in Linz, a city on the river Danube in Austria. The Ars Electronica festival grounds are located directly on the banks of the river Danube.

The adjective *»weltweit«* (worldwide) is an attribute of the adjective *»wichtigste«* (most important)!

The adjective *»wichtigste«* is an attribute of *»Festival«.* This means, that this festival ist the most important. But the festival itself is not worldwide. But its importance is worldwide. Ars Electronica is not only the most important festival of Austria, it is also not only the most important festival of Europe. It is the most important festival of the world. One way to say this is

> Die Ars Electronica ist das wichtigste Festival der Welt.
> Ars Electronica is the most important festival in the world.

But a fully equivalent way to express the exactly same meaning is this:

> Die Ars Electronica ist das weltweit wichtigste Festival.
> Ars Electronica is the worldwide most important festival. = Ars Electronica is the world's most important festival.

---

Adjectives can be attributes of nouns:

> Der **große Mann** trinkt. = The **big man** drinks.
> Die **rote Blume** blüht. = The **red flower** blooms.

But they can also be attributes of other parts of speech:

- Adjectives as attributes of verbs

  > Das Herz **schlägt unermüdlich.** = The heart **beats tirelessly.**
  > Monika **schläft lange.** = Monika **sleeps long.**
- Adjectives as attributes of adjectives

  > Dieses Buch ist **unglaublich spannend.** = This book is **incredibly exciting.**
  > Georg ist **außergewöhnlich klug.** = Georg is **exceptionally clever.**
- Adjectives as attributes of participles

  > Dr. Gruber sprach von **sorgfältig durchgeführten** Arbeiten. = Dr. Gruber spoke of **carefully performed** work.
  > Ich werde versuchen, die **langsam steigende** Sonne zu filmen. = I will try to film the **slowly rising** sun.

---

Finally, I would like to note that *Ars Electronica* is indeed known worldwide and is also a very important festival, but to say that it is *"the most important festival in the world"* is only appropriate if you consider only festivals of electronic art (electronic music, electronic performances, etc.).

Comment: As attribute of verb seems like adverbial usage and as attribute of adjectives resembles particles of degree, does it not